# How to catch the index of a part of string an arraylist contains?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm looking for word "Verb" on my obj3 named arraylist.There are 4 elements on the arraylist and the word "Verb" is a part of last element of arraylist.So i have to get the index which element of arraylist has.For example i have 4 elements on that list and the word "Verb" is a part of last element(3).Program should return 3.Here's what i tried.

```
for (String fromArray : obj3) {
        if (fromArray.contains("Verb")) 
        {
           System.out.println("Catched at"+" ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to do `fromArray.indexOf("Verb")` to get the index. don't know why you're using a `for` loop though...

Comment: it gives -1 because it is a part of a string not an element of string completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is not made available when using the enhanced for loop.

You must do one of the two following to know the index:

1. Access the ArrayList by index.
2. Keep track of the index yourself.

Here is an example of option two (2):

```
int index = 0;

for (final String currentValue : someArrayList)
{
   System.out.println("index: " + index);
   ... do something useful.
   index += 1;
}
```

Option 2 is often better than option 1 when you are iterating through a `List` and don't know the concrete implementation class.